# Query to merge 2 rows from one column into 1 row with 2 columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to process a querystring and create records out of them.

Originally the format was an escaped string in this format:

```
relativeFilePath1^relativeFilePath2^relativeFilePath3^relativeFilePath4
```

where the ^ character was escaped with %5E. Is used to split the string at this posistion, created a temporary table, inserted everything in it and fired a Insert into from there.

```
DECLARE @SplittetList TABLE(ID int Identity(1,1), fPath nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO @SplittetList SELECT * FROM Schema.fnSplit('relativeFilePath1%5ErelativeFilePath2%5ErelativeFilePath3%5ErelativeFilePath4', '%5E')
--additional processing
```

Now the format is about to change so that after every file path, there is also additional field of metadata to this file, also seperated with a ^ character. If I split this now I am getting a result like this:

```
ID |  fPath
---------------------
1  |  relativeFilePath1
2  |  metadata1
3  |  relativeFilePath2
4  |  metadata2
5  |  relativeFilePath3
6  |  metadata3
n  |  ...
```

How can I transform this list, so that the result is a set of data in this format:

```
filepath           |     metadata
----------------------------------
relativeFilePath1  |     metadata1
relativeFilePath2  |     metadata2
relativeFilePath3  |     metadata3
...
```

Comment: You have to define some sort of ordering in the result set returned by the UDF.

Comment: The only order which is possible from my perspective would be by the generated ID.

Comment: I mean you have to know somehow that `metadata1` *follows* `relativeFilePath1`. The table expression returned by the UDF is just an unordered set.

Comment: I have to assume this. The format defined for the parameter doesn't allow any other order. The parameter will definitley have this format.

Comment: Yes, but you can modify the UDF to return some sort of index for each and every substring contained in the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Data table
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    fPath nvarchar(max)
)

insert @Data values
('relativeFilePath1'),('metadata1'),('relativeFilePath2'),('metadata2'),('relativeFilePath3'),('metadata3')

-- ROW_NUMBER to ensure the ID is continuous
;with data as 
(
    select *, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id)+1)/2 as grp, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id)+1)%2 as columnno 
    from @Data
)
-- Subquery verison
select 
    (select fPath from data where grp = d.grp and columnno = 0) as filepath, 
    (select fPath from data where grp = d.grp and columnno = 1) as metadata
from data d group by grp

-- Inner join version
--select a.fPath, b.fPath from data a inner join data b on a.grp = b.grp
--where a.columnno = 0 and b.columnno = 1
```

Comment: This returns the expected result. Thanks Eric.